# Find and replace values with counters

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file that has values like:

```
location 100 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
location 150 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
location 160 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
```

I want to replace the SlotNumber like SlotNumber:

```
location 100 SlotNumber1
location 150 SlotNumber2
location 160 SlotNumber3
...
```

Please note that the 100 and 1 doesn't have any relevance. 
I was looking to use some kind of of a counter within sed and replace SlotNumber with "SlotNumber+Counter" and increment it after every match.

I don't know how many occurrences are there in that file.

Comment: Should the `Number` suffix be derived from the preceding numeric field, or just created sequentially?

Comment: Just so we're clear: You're asking how to add line numbers at the ends of the lines?  Or is the number in the second column significant?

Comment: @steeldriver: Great minds think alike, huh?

Comment: @G-Man hehe yes I guess so (or addled minds perhaps)

Comment: Your question implies that there are other lines, how can you distinguish from the lines that should have a number added (in whatever way: see the other comments) and those that should not?

Answer (score 5):

Starting off with a basic file here...

```
$ cat file
location 100 Number
location 101 Number
location 102 Number
```

We can match on all lines:

```
$ awk '{print $0 NR}' file 
location 100 Number1
location 101 Number2
location 102 Number3
```

it gets more complicated if there is filler somewhere in the middle.  You have to have a separate counter tallying up the number of times you see a location.

```
$ cat file
location 100 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
location 150 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
location 160 SlotNumber
..some lines inbetween
```

We can print only the location lines:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {x=1} /^location/ {print $0 x++}' file
location 100 SlotNumber1
location 150 SlotNumber2
location 160 SlotNumber3
```

Or all of them, only adding numbers for slot numbers.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {x=1} {if ($3=="SlotNumber") {print $0 x++} else {print $0} }' file
location 100 SlotNumber1
..some lines inbetween
location 150 SlotNumber2
..some lines inbetween
location 160 SlotNumber3
..some lines inbetween
```

Here is a good site for some basic if-then-else explanations for awk.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like an alternate to line numbers, just in case your file has mixed up numbers like this

```
location 100 Number
location 101 Number
location 102 Number
location 104 Number
location 103 Number
..
..
location 199 Number
location 200 Number
```

You can try something like this. The assumption is that the number starts from 100.

```
while read line
do
num=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d ' '`
val=`expr $num - 100`
echo "$line$val"
done < ln.txt
```

This prints out

```
location 100 Number0
location 101 Number1
location 102 Number2
location 104 Number4
location 103 Number3
..
location 199 Number99
location 200 Number100
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Scott, simplified the echo statement and removed an unnecessary line.

Comment: `newline=\`echo $line | sed 's/$/'$val'/g'\`` and `echo $newline`?  Why not just do it the easy way: `echo "$line$val"`?  Also, while the OP never clarified the meaning of his question, he clearly showed the first line (`location 100`) getting `Number1`.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for the tip. I was merely providing an alternative, since the OP did not explicitly mention that he was looking for line numbers.